# How many complete directed graphs are there up to Isomorphism?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How many tournament graphs are there up to Isomorphism?

Context:
I am examining properties of complete directed graphs and so am trying to enumerate them on my simulation. I would like to know precisely how intractable this is.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000568

Comment: Probably really complicated as Harary initially gave an incorrect calculation